# Values retrieved from integer datatype is not showing with actual decimals

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My table name is TX_TABLE and the column for insertion is TX_AMOUNT , being 'integer'. The insertion of values say like 1234.56 for 1st row and 12345.67 for 2nd row is correctly taking place for me as I could see it by putting breakpoints. 
Now, if I retrieve the data from TX_AMOUNT column the values are shown like 
1234.56 for the 1st row which is OK and for the 2nd row it shows as 12345.7 
instead of 12345.67. If I enter a value with upto 15 digits without decimals 
there is no problem. Only when values with decimals like in 12345.67 it shows 
like 12345.7.

I give below my codes:

create table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TX_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + TX_TABLE + " (" +TX_UID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + TX_TITLE_UID + " INTEGER," + TX_AMOUNT + " INTEGER," + TX_PARTICULARS + " VARCHAR(255)," + TX_DATE+" DATE," + TX_ID + " VARCHAR(255)," + TX_NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," + TX_CONTRA + " VARCHAR(255)," + TX_LISTVIEW_DATE + " DATE);";
```

insertion:

```
public void insertTxData(String inputparticulars, String inputamount, String showSelectedTitle, String inputID, String txid, String contraYorNo){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
    if (inputparticulars.equals("") || inputparticulars.equals(null)){
        inputparticulars= "particulars not entered";
    }
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS,inputparticulars);
    // with breakpoint here, the values entered are perfectly getting in    
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, inputamount);
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_TITLE_UID, inputID);
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_ID, MainActivity.txid); 
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_LISTVIEW_DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date()));
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_NAME,showSelectedTitle);
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_CONTRA,contraYorNo);
    db.insert(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, null, contentvalues);
    String td = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
}
```

data retrieval:

```
String name = titlesofReports.tagExpensesOrIncome;
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = { helper.TX_UID, helper.TX_NAME, helper.TX_PARTICULARS, 
helper.TX_AMOUNT, helper.TX_DATE,helper.TX_CONTRA}; 
Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, (helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + "= '" + td + "'"), null, null, null,null);
gt = 0;
gt_selectedItem_number = 0; 
if (c != null) {
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
    String v_uid=(c.getString(0));
    String txTotal = (c.getString(3));
    Float dd=Float.parseFloat(txTotal);
    gt = gt + new Float(txTotal);
    BigDecimal bdtxTotal= new BigDecimal(c.getString(3));
}
```

Using breakpoints, when I verified I could see all the 4 variables like
`txTotal`,`dd1`,`dd`,`bdTxTotal` are giving the same result like **12345.7** instead of **12345.67**.

Comment: Did you check the value which is persisted in DB?
This will help isolate the problem is at DB level or at API level

Comment: Yes I checked using the breakpoint where it shows wrongly. At insertion it was OK.

Comment: This code inserts a string that looks like a floating-point number into an integer column. Please decide what the type should be.

Comment: the string inserts 12345.67 into an integer column. What type should the column be.?  If the string inserts 1234.56 it is retreived as it is. If the string inserts 12345.67 the retreived value is 12345.7

Comment: I changed the column type from +TX_AMOUNT+ " INTEGER, to FLOAT.
Changed the version number and ran the program. Still the problem persits. I get 12345.7 instead of 12345.67.